# Как объединить данные типа String при селекте?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Всем привет!
Есть некий запрос:

```
SELECT *

FROM table1

WHERE field1 not like '%text for example 1%'
AND field1 not like '%text for example 2%'
AND field1 not like '%text for example 3%'
AND field1 not like '%text for example 4%'
AND field1 not like '%text for example 5%'
```

Вопрос, можно ли объединить эти 5 искомых значений (text for example 1,2,3,4,5) объединить в некий массив, чтобы не повторять `AND field1 not like` каждый раз, при добавлении нового условия?

Пробовал через `IN (text for example 1,2,3,4,5)` но возвращает ошибку, что для формата поля строка такой оператор не работает.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почитайте про циклы в `sql`(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/syntax-of-for-loop-in-sql-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: можно текст запроса формировать динамически и потом передавать в sp_executesql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE field1 not like '%text for example [1-5]%'
```

Comment: не совсем, в строках '%text for example 1%' , '%text for example 2%' , '%text for example 3%' и т.д. разный полностью весь текст, а не только последние числа